# Update a specific number of column in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an edit action to edit my **comment** model :

```
public partial class Comment
    {
        [DisplayName("شناسه نظر")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "متن نظر را وارد کنید")]
        [DisplayName("متن نظر")]
        public string CommentText { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("تعداد پسندیدن ")]
        public long LikeCount { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("تعداد نپسندیدن")]
        public long DisLikeCount { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("تاریخ انتشار ")]
        public System.DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("وضعیت نمایش ")]
        public string Visible { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("نام کاربری ")]
        public string AutherUserName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("شناسه نظراصلی")]
        public Nullable<int> CommentFKId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("شناسه کاربر")]
        public Nullable<int> StudentId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("شناسه محتوا ")]
        public Nullable<int> ContentId { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public virtual Comment Comment1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
        public virtual Content Content { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a lot of columns in my model but in Edit action i just need to edit some of these columns.

So my Postback edit action is like this :

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Comment comment, FormCollection form)
        {
            //comment.AutherUserName = "admin";
            //comment.LikeCount = 0;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                TryUpdateModel(comment, new string[] {"CommentText", "Visible"});
                obj.Update(comment);
                obj.Save();
            }

          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Comment", new { contentID = form["ContentId"].ToString() });
        }
```

So  as you can see i want to update **commentText** and **visible**.but this code doesn't update my model .it doesn't return any error

Here is my **update** method :

```
  public void Update(Comment comment)
        {
            _dbcontext.Entry(comment).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
```

My save function :

```
 public void Save()
        {
            _dbcontext.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Best regards

Comment: post TryUpdateModel method as well

Comment: and your are using EF?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad yes i am using EF6

Comment: I don't implement this method

Comment: what is obj, its not initialzed anywhere or decalred in the action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i do this method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Comment comment, FormCollection form)
        {

            Comment temp = obj.FindCommentsById(comment.Id);
            temp.CommentText = comment.CommentText;
            temp.Visible = comment.Visible;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //TryUpdateModel(comment, new string[] {"CommentText", "Visible"});
                obj.Update(temp);
                obj.Save();
            }

          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Comment", new { contentID = form["ContentId"].ToString() });
        }
```

First i edit the columns that i want after that i pass the id of the record to **FindCommentsById** and changes the values of returned entity to new one.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
public void Update(Comment comment)
        {
            _dbcontext.Entry(comment).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

you are updating the object, but not saving it to reflect the object changes in the database.

Comment: No ehsan i save it ,but i seperate my save function in my repository

Comment: it is my repository class:        private readonly CommentRepository obj = new CommentRepository();

Comment: you should save call SaveChanges in the update method

Comment: but you have not even decalred or initialized in action, how its gonaa work, i am not clear about the code you have posted, is it complete?

Comment: when you call Save function?

Comment: if you show your tryupdatemodel function, then i can guide you much better

Comment: As you can in my post after my update method  i call save function

Comment: hmm, right but what is happening in TryUpdateModel method?